# Puppeteer - Get Information of open tabs like url in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, tabs, puppeteer

I want to do a script that opens a web page and that web page should have information of other opened tabs in the browser.

means that nodejs server should have the information of currently all the open tabs. is it possible?

```
chrome.tabs
```

Comment: What "information" are you talking about? Puppeteer has `browser.pages()` which is a list of the tabs. What are you trying to accomplish with this and what code have you written so far?

Comment: "browser.pages()" this is it. i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer has Browser.pages to list all the tabs.